# jQuery cropper plugin - Rotate and Scale don't work at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

If someone goes to fengyuanchen cropper and do something like this: click on ScaleX (or scaleY) and then click on rotate, the cropper is not working, the area selected is not correct. Remember just click once in Scale and once in rotate. This is the function getSourceCanvas, that manage the cropper action. But I can't see where is wrong in order to fixed. Something is wrong, that's for sure.

```
function getSourceCanvas(image, data) {
    var canvas = $('<canvas>')[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var dstX = 0;
   var dstY = 0;
   var dstWidth = data.naturalWidth;
   var dstHeight = data.naturalHeight;
   var rotate = data.rotate;
   var scaleX = data.scaleX;
   var scaleY = data.scaleY;
   var scalable = isNumber(scaleX) && isNumber(scaleY) && (scaleX !== 1 || scaleY !== 1);
   var rotatable = isNumber(rotate) && rotate !== 0;
   var advanced = rotatable || scalable;
   var canvasWidth = dstWidth * abs(scaleX || 1);
   var canvasHeight = dstHeight * abs(scaleY || 1);
   var translateX;
   var translateY;
   var rotated;

  if (scalable) {
    translateX = canvasWidth / 2;
    translateY = canvasHeight / 2;
  }

 if (rotatable) {
   rotated = getRotatedSizes({
     width: canvasWidth,
     height: canvasHeight,
     degree: rotate
   });

   canvasWidth = rotated.width;
   canvasHeight = rotated.height;
   translateX = canvasWidth / 2;
   translateY = canvasHeight / 2;
 }

 canvas.width = canvasWidth;
 canvas.height = canvasHeight;

 if (advanced) {
   dstX = -dstWidth / 2;
   dstY = -dstHeight / 2;

   context.save();
   context.translate(translateX, translateY);
 }

 if (rotatable) {
   context.rotate(rotate * Math.PI / 180);
 }

 // Should call `scale` after rotated
 if (scalable) {
   context.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
 }


 context.drawImage(image, floor(dstX), floor(dstY), floor(dstWidth), floor(dstHeight));

 if (advanced) {
   context.restore();
 }

  return canvas;
}
```